# Remove all Right to Left Characters in discord.js leaderboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hello there I just wanted to ask if there is a way to remove all right-to-left characters. I am aware of
`.replace(/\u200f/g, "")` and `.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "")` but they have not really helped with my leaderboards since the former still doesn't remove the rtl characters and the latter only removes all non-ascii characters which also involves characters that aren't written from left to right. if there was a possible fix for replacing all characters from languages that are read from right to left, i would be very grateful

Here is the sample input

```
acc.tag.replace(/\u200f/g, "")
```

and here is the sample output

```
 1. PersonA#1333 - 8052.7x
 2. PersonB#3169 - 8035.3x
 3. PersonC#7619 - 7541x
PersonD#7797 - 7529.5x. 4
```

or when I do  `.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "")`
it outputs the following(sample):

```
 4. PersonA#1333 - 8052.7x
 5. PersonB#3169 - 8035.3x
 6. PersonC#7619 - 7541x
 4. #4327 - 6553.4x
```

in the above scenario, it replaced  as "" since it consists of non ASCII characters but its not a rtl text.

Comment: can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: sure, i just edited the question so you can see the sample output

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this RegExp `/[\u04c7-\u0591\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F4\u0600-\u06FF]/gi`.

It matches both Hebrew and Arabic, and doesn't match Emojis or special non-RTL Unicode characters. See the regexr tests [here](http://regexr.com/66e6p)

Comment: sadly it still doesnt change the result, as the text seems to be still bidirectional